# AWS - Amazon Email Service

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am trying to send an email using Amazon SES. But i am stuck in an issue.

In order to implement Amazon SES, I have downloaded AWS SDK and installed it successfully.

It exposed the Email send classes under

Amazon
Amazon.SimpleEmail
Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model

However, I am unable to successfully send an email using sample code provided in SDK as well as on internet.
While attempting to send email following exception has been encountered:

===========================================

## Welcome to the AWS .NET SDK!

> Caught Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match
>   the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and
>   signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
>   Response Status Code: Forbidden Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
>   Error Type: Unknown Request ID: 21941641-ec1e-4845-83d8-d719dd5c822e
>   XML: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
>   `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The
>   request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for
>   details.21941641-ec1e-4845-83d8-d719dd5c822e
>
> Caught Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match
>   the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and
>   signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
>   Response Status Code: Forbidden Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
>   Error Type: Unknown Request ID: 75963720-0392-46db-d92f-5c5d2452836e
>   XML: 
>   `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The
>   request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for
>   details.

`</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>75963720-0392-46db-d92f-5c5d2452836e</RequestID></Response>`

> Caught Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match
>   the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
>   Response Status Code: Forbidden Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch
>   Request ID: 0E68EC31B70065EE XML: 
>   `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your key and signing method.47 45
>   54 0a 0a 0a 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 64 61 74 65 3a 54 68 75 2c 20 30 32
>   20 46 65 62 20 32 30 31 32 20 32 33 3a 31 32 3a 31 32 20 47 4d 54 0a
>   2f0E68EC31B70065EEwGEFXVvobchvu85xzk++jrayRuz6lOB8VlT6vDEArnKwoFXrHKVNMaTB+7MrIY3dBD2hoIwqTf45ZMRKO2oeOqw+bP4=GET
>   x-amz-date:Thu, 02 Feb 2012 23:12:12 GMT
>   `/</StringToSign><AWSAccessKeyId></AWSAccessKeyId></Error>`

Can any body help me out?
Waiting for your valuable response.

Thanks,
Xprt.

Comment: Hey - I haven't got SES running but I checked with SNS. It seems the error you get is simply a matter of setting the wrong keys. I had to create a new user with keys to use SNS. You probably have tried this already and can/should not post your keys here, but don't you think something has gotten mixed up?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you've read through all their comments and set the necessary values correctly.  Make sure you uncomment any of the appropriate lines.
2. Make sure you created a new access key for yourself and you're not trying to use the default one (or commented out one? I don't remember.)
3. Verify that you didn't copy any trailing spaces with your secret access key and that it was copied over correctly.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. I have gone through each and every thing. It all seems OK. Futhermore, on google there are several examples which have state forward code.
I have tried those as well but failed.